# Html.CheckBox onclick event is getting escaped

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to generate a series of check boxes that will update a span to keep track of the number of check boxes that have been checked (shows something like "4 of 12 checked").  I've created the JavaScript function `updateSelected` that handles that, but it requires the ID of the span and the class of the check boxes to count, so I tried this code to generate each check box:

```
@Html.CheckBox(string.Format("contentprofilestate[{0}].selected", i), 
  new { onclick = "updateSelected('" + selectedSpanId + "', '" + checkboxClass + "')" })
```

This produces the following HTML:

```
<input id="contentprofilestate_6__selected" name="contentprofilestate[6].selected" 
 onclick="updateSelected(&#39;StMarySpan&#39;, &#39;StMaryCheck&#39;)"
 type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

How can I get the `onclick` event handler to render without escaping the apostrophes?  Alternatively, is there a better way to accomplish this task (if so, feel free to use jQuery in your suggestion)?

**Note re: Lester**

I created a new project and created this view and it still escaped the apostrophes:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "index";
}

<h2>index</h2>

@Html.CheckBox(string.Format("contentprofilestate[{0}].selected", 0), new { onclick = "updateSelected('" + "test" + "', '" + "test2" + "')" })
```

**Alternate Solution**

I was not able to figure out how to keep the apostrophes from being escaped, so I wrote some jQuery logic to do what I need without any inline JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(':checkbox').click(function () {
        var clientHeader = jQuery(this).closest('.client-header');
        var clientCheckedSpan = clientHeader.find('.client-checked');
        var inputChecked = clientHeader.find('input:checked');
        clientCheckedSpan.text(inputChecked.length);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the function actually being called?

Comment: No, but that's because the inline JavaScript is not outputting correctly. I am comfortable making sure updateSelected() works correctly if I can get it to be called properly via the onclick handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very odd that the apostrophes are being encoded. I didn't think they would be and after doing a quick test they aren't. There's probably something else going on in that view. If you place just that 1 line in an empty view I'm betting you won't get the same problem.

As for any other alternatives, you can easily get the number of selected checkboxes using jQuery:

```
var numChecked = $("input:checked[id^=contentprofilestate]").size();
```

Comment: +1 for this answer. It's easier to just do the selection using what's already there (and, also, you're avoiding inline JavaScript).

Comment: I have a number of clients that each have their own section, and I want to count each group of check boxes separately.  That was the reason for passing the class (which encodes the client) and the span (which is in the client's header).  I'm checking into the empty view to see if I can identify where the encoding is happening, but do you have any thoughts on the right way to make sure only the correct subset of check boxes is counted?